# Which part is the tail in 人参{にんじん}の尻尾{しっぽ}

Tags: words, food

What is meant by a "carrot tail"?

> 人参{にんじん}の尻尾{しっぽ}

Is it the green part or the orange part?
A google image search does not really help, since "carrot" comes up in every one, but no picture I have found has arrows with labels for the parts of a carrot :D

https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/word/%E4%BA%BA%E5%8F%82%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%BB%E5%B0%BE/

Comment: Try to google "人参の頭", which is the other part and you'll see clearly that the tail is the (other) part, buried deeper in the soil. I tried to google 人参の尻尾 but there are indeed no clear result that can help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yuuichi Tam says, this is the orange thin part of the root. You could also have deduced this by elimination: the green part would undoubtedly be 人参の葉っぱ (also in recipes).

Answer (score 3):

It is the tip of the orange part, not leaves of carrot.